# ScaleTransform and Image size

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have a Canvas which has an image as background. When I do the ScaleTransform to increase the size of the image, the image blows out of the Canvas. Although I increase the size, I don't want the image to go out of the Canvas, I just want it to fit inside the Canvas. How to fix this issue in WPF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set ClipToBounds=True on the Canvas